# Import LDraw models into Blender

Tags: objects, import, file-format

I have been making models using [LDraw](http://ldraw.org).

What's the best way to import LDraw models into Blender?

Comment: I used to do this a little while ago. I would use LDraw as a in between for LDD and Blender. It was a lot of fun. I'll try to get back into it for a bit so I can answer this for you.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain. This question is short, but the content would be cluttered with more information.